# Get all values of some identifiers with same name in a GET request

Tags: php

I have a GET request like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?fg=1&fg=3&fg=16&fg=54&fg=64&s=1
```

and I want to extract all values of the `fg` identifier.

So the result should be like this:

```
array(
    [0]  => "1",
    [1] => "3",
    [2] => "16",
    [3] => "54,
    [4] => "64",
)
```

I tried to use

```
$_GET['fg']
```

but $_GET is an associative array of variables so it contains only one element indexed by `fg`.

So any idea on how I can get all values of that `fg` identifiers?

Comment: That does not work, they have to be unique

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `fg` into an array.  Instead of doing `fg=1`, try: `fg[]=1`.  The `[]` turn it into an array.

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?fg[]=1&fg[]=3&fg[]=16&fg[]=54&fg[]=64&s=1
```

If you do it this way, then `$_GET['fg']` will be an array.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend changing your URL / query-string to an array format instead:

```
http://localhost/mysite/index.php?fg[]=1&fg[]=3&fg[]=16&fg[]=54&fg[]=64&s=1
```

That way, when you access `$_GET['fg']`, it's an array and you can access it as such:

```
foreach ($_GET['fg'] as $fg) {
    // whatever
}
```

However, if you don't take this approach, you could work some magic via [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$fg = array();
$parts = explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    list($key, $value) = explode('=', $part);
    if ($key == 'fg') {
        $fg[] = $value;
    }
}
// now $fg contains all individual values =]
```

[**Codepad Example**](http://codepad.org/HWHNh7sh) of the second sample